# Visual Studio Code not opening after aborted update

Tags: visual-studio-code

Premise: I am using Windows 7. I installed VS Code last week and today, when I opened it, it informed me of an update available. I tried to update it, but it signalled some error during the update operation (sorry but I don't remember which error it was), so I clicked "abort". Now if I try to open VS Code, an error popup appears instead:
[A JavaScript error occurred in the main process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7qq6.png)

I suppose something went wrong while rolling back when I aborted the update. Is there a way to fix this without reinstalling the program?

Answer (score 0):

looks like corrupted project file. create a new empty project and import all files in the new project. problem will be gone.